# Disable checkbox column based on user authorization

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I have a grid and in the grid I have two Item Template columns - Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 2.
I want to disable the whole Checkbox 1 column based on if a user is an admin or general user.
So say, if a user is an 'admin', I want both columns to be enabled and user can check/uncheck both the columns.
But, if a user is 'general user', I want to disable 'Checkbox1', so that user can only check/uncheck Checkbox 2. But can see values for 'Checkbox 1' column and can't edit it or make changes.
Presently, I am achieving this behavior as below-

```
    protected void grdchkbox_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkbox1 = (e.Row.FindControl("Checkbox1") as CheckBox);
            if (IsGeneralUser(empid))
            {
                chkbox1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is the page load time.
It is checking for user's role everytime a row is bound which means making db calls at each row bound.
Also, it's disabling a checkbox for each row separately.
Is there a way, I can disable the whole checkbox 1 column in one go?

Comment: Could you check if the user is in a certain role first, store that value and then enable or disable that row depending on that value? Prior to binding the gridview? Saving the need to go to the db for each row check?

Comment: did my answer help you at all?

Comment: thanks psoshmo.. It worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on how your gridview is setup, you could try just disabling editing on the column or making it read only.

You could also simply save the users status in a session variable, so that you only have to make the db call the first time, which should speed up the whole process as well.

Using a session variable would look something like:

```
 protected void grdchkbox_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox1 = (e.Row.FindControl("Checkbox1") as CheckBox);
        //we check to see if we already have the users status saved in session
        var isUser = HttpContext.Current.Session["IsGeneralUser"];
        //if we dont, we run the IsGeneralUser method and save the result in session
        if(isUser == null)
        {
            isUser = IsGeneralUser(empid);
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("IsGeneralUser", isUser);
        }
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(isUser))
        {
            chkbox1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```